# SharePoint Theme Color Switcher in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

How do i create a theme color switcher in public facing internet site in SharePoint 2013
in user level.i'm attaching the image where do i need to create the switcher.Could anyone help?[image]

Comment: Hi Nishad, in its current format the question is to open ended for the Q&A style site that SE is. If you supply the exact version of SharePoint you are dealing with, how you need the switcher to behave, what part of sp you are emulating with this functionality, then perhaps someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of is to save the selected color value in a Cookie and refresh the page via JavaScript..

Show/hide the `<style src="">` (maybe enclose it in a div and give proper Ids to the div) based on the Cookie value..

You will need to differentiate the colors with the CSS only, and load appropriate css at runtime..

Comment: If that helped, please mark it as answer to close the question..